# How to update submodules in a gitlab CI/CD

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-submodules

I have a project organized in the following tree

```
|.
|..
|-- devops
|-- project1
|-- project2
```

In the devops folder, I have included the other two projects as submodules, since these two projects are developed independently by two different teams.

```
|.
|..
|-- project1@0deed0fa
|-- project2@0beef0fb
|-- .gitlab-ci.yml
```

I have setup the pipeline to deploy the projects. Whenever there are new commits on any of the projects, a trigger is setup to run the `devops` project pipeline. As part of the devops jobs, I run `git submodule` commands to fetch and merge. Then build. It works.

The problem I have is, over a period of time, there are a lot of changes made to the submodules. The changes from the last submodule commit to the devops project folder is replayed every time there is a commit on any of the projects. Once a month, I manually update the `devops` project folder and update to the latest commit of the submodule projects. I can commit the changes from the devops pipeline task, but that will generate new pipeline in the same devops  pipeline. (I didn't test it but it seems obvious).

Is there any way I can update the submodules to the latest commit as part of the devops pipeline ?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I don't think submodules are the best approach. Please see my answer below for a better way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Only Build Your Binaries Once

Using git submodules are not the best practice for implementing an integration pipeline. The seminal book [Continuous Delivery](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/continuous-delivery-reliable/9780321670250/) states the following in the section `Only Build Your Binaries Once` (Chapter 5):

> Many build systems use source code held in the version control system as the canonical source for many steps. The code will be compiled repeatedly in different contexts during the commit process, again at acceptance test time, [etc.] Every time you compile the code, you run the risk of introducing some difference.

Also, recompiling takes a lot of time, resulting in longer feedback cycles. The recommendation is:

> You should only build your binaries once, during the commit stage of the build. These binaries should be stored in a filesystem somewhere [...] where it is easy to retrieve them for later stages of the pipeline.

#### CI/CD Pipeline Flow

Following this paradigm, your workflow would look something like this:

1. Developers working on feature branches in `project1` and `project2` will push a commit
2. A project pipeline is triggered that **builds** the binaries, runs unit/component tests and **packages** the container
3. If everything passes, the binaries or containers are **deployed** to a "development" repository
4. The project pipelines will trigger your downstream devops pipeline, which will **download** the binaries/containers from the repositories.
5. The devops pipeline integrates pieces and runs end-to-end tests
6. If E2E tests pass, the binaries/containers are **deployed** (aka promoted) to a `release` repository
7. If you're doing Continuous Delivery, you would deploy to production here, but many teams prefer pushing a button in a manual job

Notice how the source code is only built once.

#### Popular Binary Repositories

There are a number of popular binary repositories available. Most have a free and paid pro version. Check their websites for more info.

1. [GitLab Job Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) (between stages or pipelines)
2. [GitLab Package Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/) or [GitLab Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/)
3. [GitHub Package Registry](https://github.com/features/packages) or [GitHub Container Registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/about-github-container-registry)
4. [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/)
5. [Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus/repository-oss)
6. Cloud storage container registry ([AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/), [GCP CR](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry), [Azure CR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/))

Comment: The teams will only commit to the main branch when all tests are done. The pipeline I manage does only the end to end tests and deployment. End to End test is the issue, as both teams are independent, end to end test has to be run. I am pulling the latest from these projects with `git submodule updata --init --recursive`  then fetch and merge from specific branches. I am using docker-in-docker to do the e2e tests.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot somehow commit the submodulle hashes, so that next time the end to end test runs it picks up from the latest commit of the submodule projects, not the old commit hash in my devlops prDV82XLojects and start fetching and merging the changes from there. Unless I am missing something your solution does not address that.

Comment: I rewrote the question from scratch to address the real core of your issue. You may not like the proposed change of approach, but it's the best advice I can give.

Comment: Yes, compile binary once, make sense. I have to make an image for end to end tests and move that upstream to each project build pipeline. Then just run the end to end against the docker images. It will be added time for the project build pipeline. I am using gitlab container registry.

Comment: Thank you for time and efforts to help.

Answer (score 2):

Use CI enviroments like this:

```
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal
    GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS: --remote
```

more info in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#use-git-submodules-in-cicd-jobs)